# What (non-Mono) language/IDE should a C# developer use for Mac OS X?

Tags: c#, cocoa, macos

I have a couple of small programs that a mate of mine needs ported to OS X. I've used Mono to get a couple other things working on a Mac before, but while it made the port extremely easy, it just seemed a bit unwieldy. For the apps that I'm making I don't want to have to force the person to download and install the Mono framework, nor do I want to have to teach them how to open up a terminal, navigate to the application's directory, and have to use the `mono appname.exe` command.

I'm an absolute lover of Visual Studio and C#. Because of this, I'd like for my OS X development experience to be as similar to that as possible. I don't mind learning a new language in order to code for OS X, but I would like a visual designer for the GUI so that I can easily make the interface, and it'd be nice for the language to be at least somewhat similar to C# as well, although this isn't as big a requirement so long as the IDE is decently helpful. With Visual Studio I learn a lot just from the code-completion that it offers (who honestly wants to memorize a Classes' every property and method..? :) ).

**What I'm looking for**:

```
a) Good graphical interface designer that makes native-looking OS X GUIs
b) Back-end language that won't seem totally foreign to a C# developer
c) Something that runs natively on OS X without a framework needing to be installed
d) As many Visual Studio-like features as possible. (code completion, hints, etc)
```

**Also, what is the native interface called?** I see references to **Cocoa**, **GTK**, **and a few others**. I'd like to just use the standard Mac bits, assuming that's reasonable. All I generally need in my apps are pretty standard components like DataGridViews, ComboBoxes, TreeViews, TextBoxes, Buttons, Labels, etc.

Suggestions?

Thanks yet again.

-Sootah

Comment: Another option is to bundle your mono app into a native bundle using macpack: http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your requirements can be satisfied with Xcode and its associated tools. There is big things afoot in improvements to Xcode that are available to developers now, but not to the general public. Expect those in the near future. Some of these changes are more like what you're used to in VS. I can't say more about it right now I'm afraid.

That said, the way the tools exist now are certainly more than suitable for your requirements, Xcode and Interface Builder. You won't be able to use C# I'm afraid in that environment, but as you said you don't mind learning a new language, might I suggest you learn Objective-C. It's quite simply the path of least resistance for mac development; and Cocoa is the native UI.

Comment: That's like saying bleeding to death is the path of least resistance for the guillotine. :)

Comment: Actually, bleeding to death would not be the path of least resistance for the guillotine. You'd first have to find something to skewer yourself or have someone skewer you with, then trot along until you bleed out. Whereas you could use that time to make a run directly to the guillotine and off your head.

Comment: Aqua is the native UI, but Cocoa is the main avenue to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Objective-C/XCode to program for Mac OS X, even though it is *very* different from C#/Visual Studio.  I'm going through this process myself (switching from being a Windows Mobile developer to an iPhone developer), and it's best if you free yourself from the expectation that things in the Mac world will ever be much like they are in the .Net world.

Comment: @Joe Blow: I must clarify that *I* don't make music - I make software that *other* people use to make music. So I'm more like Stradivarius than Mozart. :)

Comment: @Joe: you should un-delete your answer here. You overuse exclamation points, but otherwise you seem to know what you're talking about on this subject.

Comment: @Joe: by an amazing coincidence, I now really wanna shy away from any sort of argumentative issues with you!!!!!!!